# Simplification of equation in 2 variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I was solving [This](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1983_AIME_Problems/Problem_4) sum and in the 1st solution they got the equation as $$\sqrt{50}^2 = y^2 + (6-x)^2$$ and $$\sqrt{50}^2 = x^2 + (y + 2)^2$$ 
I tried solving the equations but was not able to simplify it to obtain a value for $x^2 + y^2$. Can someone please tell me how they arrived at $x = 1$ and $y = 5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$y^{2} + (6-x)^{2} = 50 = x^{2} + (y+2)^{2}$$
expanding, 
$$y^{2}+36-12x+x^{2} = x^{2} + y^{2} + 4y + 4$$
the quadratic terms cancel, leaving
$$y=8-3x$$
substituting this back into one of the two original equations gives
$$(8-3x)^{2}+(6-x)^{2} = 50$$
$$64-48x+9x^{2}+36-12x+x^{2}=50$$
$$10x^{2}-60x+50=0$$
$$x^{2}-6x+5=0$$
So $x=1,5$. Substituting back, we get $y=5,-7$ respectively. If we insist that $y$ is positive, then $(1,5)$ is the only solution.

Comment: Haha I just did the exact same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The other solution is perfect, although I find it nicer to visualize. Both equations you have describe circles with radius of $\sqrt{50}$ and centers $(0, -2)$ and $(6, 0)$.

[image: visualization]

The line passing through the centers is $y = \frac13x-2$ and the midpoint $M$ of the centers is $(3, -1)$. We know that the points we are looking for (call them $A$ and $B$) are on the perpendicular bisector of the line, thus this is the line passing through $M$ and perpendicular to the line $y = \frac13x-2$. Hence, we know that $A$ and $B$ should be on the line 
$$y=-3x+8.$$

The distance from the centers to the $M$ is $\sqrt{10}$. Since the radius is $\sqrt{50}$ we know that the $AM=BM=\sqrt{40}=2\sqrt{10}$, i.e., the same as the distance between the centers of the circles! From here it is easy to see that
\begin{align}
x &= 3 \pm 2,\\
y &= -1 \mp 6.
\end{align}
Hence, we have $A$ at $(1, 5)$ and $B$ at $(5, -7)$.